# How to install HAProxy and configure it in an ubuntu server?

Tags: haproxy

I know I have asked this question before but i didn't get any answers for it.

How to install `HAProxy` and configure it in an `Ubuntu server`. I want to use it to map applications listening on various ports to specific URLs.

For example, if an app called page-designer is listening at `http://IP:5000`, then it should map it to `http://IP/page-designer`.

I have already installed the HAProxy package using `sudo apt-get -y install haproxy`.  But what changes do I have to do in `HAProxy` main configuration file located at `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` before restarting the `HAProxy` service for the changes to take effect.  And mainly after this how can I map my apps running on various ports to specific URLs like mentioned above?

haproxy.cfg

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
        #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-in
    mode    http

    bind *:80

    acl path-page-designer              path_beg -i /employeeList    
    use_backend page-designer-backend   if path-page-designer
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

backend page-designer-backend
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor

    http-request set-path /

    server  appserver1 206.189.22.155:5000
```

Comment: You'll probably have more luck with getting an answer if you ask on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand how haproxy works, you can find the essential config in:

https://www.haproxy.com/blog/the-four-essential-sections-of-an-haproxy-configuration/

In your case, you can try something like this...

```
frontend http-in
    mode    http

    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/your-cert.pem

    http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

    acl path-page-designer              path_beg -i /page-designer    
    use_backend page-designer-backend   if path-page-designer

backend page-designer-backend
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor

    http-request set-path /

    server  appserver1 206.189.22.155:5000
```

Comment: hi i have updated my question with the contents of my haproxy.cfg file

Comment: as you can see i have tried what you have said..but hitting http://206.189.22.155/page-designer is showing me "Cannot GET /page-designer"

Comment: and when i hit just hit http://206.189.22.155/ it shows me 503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.

Comment: can you tell me if i have made any mistakes in my haproxy.cfg file?

Comment: also someone told me i have to do this using http-request set-path to rewrite the requested path

Comment: OK, i test the config... you need to add: "http-request set-path /" in backend.

Comment: you mean i have to add http-request set-path /page-designer in the backend or just http-request set-path /

Comment: I updated my code in the question like how you said, but I am still getting 503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.

Comment: I have a node.js app running on http://206.189.22.155:5000/employeeList and iam trying to map it to port 80 ie,it should be accessible at http://206.189.22.155/employeeList

Comment: sorry it is actually /employeeList and not /page-designer

Comment: but the issue still persists ie i am getting 503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request even though there is the app is running on 206.189.22.155:5000/employeeList

Comment: hi the problem is now resolved.I tried this on a diffrent server and now its working.Thank you so much!!

Comment: do you know how i can map the ports dynamically like how you showed in haproxy using a generic script ?

Comment: yes exactly.A generic script that can be used for all application to automatically remap the ports just like how it is in this example!!

Comment: Also I'd like to redirect all requests on port 80 to port 443 ie,redirecting http to https (ssl).So i added redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc } in the front-end.But only http works and not https.

Comment: I  have updated my config in the question.Plz help!

Comment: Hi i tried the configuration but iam getting [ALERT] 261/075950 (23502) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:43] : 'bind *:443                                                                                        ' : unable to load SSL certificate file '/etc/ssl/certs/your-cert.pem' file does                                                                                         not exist.[ALERT] 261/075950 (23502) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy  Fatal errors found in configuration.

Comment: I  have certbot installed on my ubuntu server but how to generate a certificate using that?